# Attempted to call function "openssl_pkey_get_private" from namespace "WAYF"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, php-7.2

I'm getting this error message

> Attempted to call function "openssl_pkey_get_private" from namespace "WAYF"

I'm upgrading the symfony version from symfony2 to symfony3, and "WAYF" is my bundle and

In that I have one class name as "CustomLogin.php"

in that class I have declared one function "function prepareparamsforjs(){}" and

in that function I'm calling "openssl_pkey_get_private()" function with arguments "$privatekey" and "$privatekeypass" to get a private Key

but I'm getting above error message.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you don't have the OpenSSL extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) loaded in PHP, so the parser is trying to find it inside the current namespace, which is the WAYF.

A quick way to verify if the OpenSSL extension is loaded is to run:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl'));
```

Comment: yes, after var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl'));

 I'm getting bool(false)

How Should I solve this, How to include this openssl?
I have checked in php.ini file the extension is enabled "extension=php_openssl.dll"

Comment: 1. make sure you're checking/editing right php.ini - on Windows there are some PHP distributions which uses C:\Windows\php.ini, etc. Location of used php.ini can be checked by 'phpinfo();', 2. make sure that lines with extensions you want to be loaded are not commented, 3. check the `extension_dir` param in php.ini if it point to the folder where the extension dlls are

Comment: Yes, actually I have various version of PHP installed and the path of current php version is not set in "environment variables". That's why the issue is occurred.
I have set the environment variables path now its working fine.
Thanks :)